# Python package cannot find one of its modules after installation

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I am trying to build a Python package. For simplification, I will only mention the parts which are relevant to the problem:
The package (directory) is called `moranpycess` and inside it there are three relevant files:

1. The initfile for the whole package `__init__.py`:

```
from .Individual import Individual
from .MoranProcess import MoranProcess
```

2. A module called `Individual` which contains a class `Individual`.
3. A module called `MoranProcess` which contains a class `MoranProcess`. At the top it imports the previous module with: `import Individual`.

I install the package with `python -m pip install .`
Then I run a test to see if the package can be imported properly: `python -c 'import moranpycess'`.

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/runner/work/angry-moran-simulator/angry-moran-simulator/moranpycess/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .MoranProcess import MoranProcess
  File "/home/runner/work/angry-moran-simulator/angry-moran-simulator/moranpycess/MoranProcess.py", line 22, in <module>
    import Individual
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Individual'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This is strange to me since it seems that the Python interpreter can find the package, the package imports the respective classes but the interpreter also tries to execute the top-level module imports and (I don't know why) it does not find the module...
Am I doing something wrong here?

#### EDIT:

directory structure:

```
└── moranpycess
    ├── Individual.py
    ├── MoranProcess.py
    └── __init__.py
```

#### Update

I am considering the solution proposed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375740/2340598
However I don't know if this is the "right" way to organize a package...

Comment: Try removing the `.` before the values.

Comment: maybe you should use relative import with dot `import .Individual` or `from . import Individual`. OR maybe you should use again `from .Individual import Individual`

Comment: @furas: (1) is SyntaxError, (2) and (3) yield another problem `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: you should show structure of folders and files - so we could reproduce this situation and test it.

Comment: @furas: Added explicit directory `tree`

Comment: The answer you linked is horrid, please don't use it. Can you import with `from moranpycess.Individual import Individual` instead?

Comment: @Arne: This seems to work... Then in the initfile for the package I have `from .MoranProcess import MoranProcess` because if the user imports the whole package (intended usecase) I want to present the `MoranProcess` class directly in pkg's namespace. Would you say that setup is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative imports are a bit harder to get right than absolute imports. They are also more brittle (e.g., if you move a file doing the import, it breaks), so unless you have a good reason to use relative imports I'd suggest to just use absolute ones.

Following that, your public API as it is defined in your topmost `__init__.py` would look like this:

```py
from moranpycess.MoranProcess import MoranProcess

__all__ = ["MoranProcess"]  # import hint that some tools use
```

While non-public objects can still be imported internally (e.g. in `MoranProcess.py`) in the following way:

```py
from moranpycess.Individual import Individual
```

The good thing about absolute imports is that no matter where in your package (or outside of it) you are, they always look the same.

---

If done like this, users that have installed your package should be able to use your objects like this:

```py
from moranpycess import MoranProcess  # directly gets the object, not module
```

You should try to avoid messing with `sys.path` in order to get your imports to work, mainly because it isn't necessary. If all you're doing is writing regular python code that is meant to be used in a regular way, the builtin import mechanics should serve your use cases just fine.

If I were to import a package and noticed that `sys.path` changed, I'd suspect shenanigans and start looking for an alternative.

Comment: I am not sure `from moranpycess.Individual import Individual ` is required in the initfile since it is an internal class only used (and imported) by the `MoranProcess` module, not by the user. And I do not want to expose it to the user. Following that, I don't think it should be in the `__all__` field too... Would that be OK to remove it? Would the `MoranProcess` module still find it? and if so - how should it import the class `Individual`?

Comment: I see, seems I misunderstood a little. Does it fit your problem now?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!